# Present UIAlertController from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to show an `UIAlertController` from a `UIBarButtonItem`, just like in the web browser in the Facebook app when clicking the actions button. But haven't been successful. Been searching on Stack Overflow, Google, Github etc, but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Here you can see how it looks like in the Facebook app: [UIAlertController in the Facebook app](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CD1PPddVIAAILsY.jpg)

Below is the code I've tried, but I've noticed that the `popoverPresentationController` property is `nil`.

```
func showActionSheet(sender: AnyObject) {
    var optionsAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    // Add the actions

    optionsAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    optionsAlert.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender as! UIBarButtonItem

    presentViewController(optionsAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Would be very thankful if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Really? Are you sure? It shouldn't be nil. It's not if I run the code above.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I don't know how many ways I've tried to make it work. I tried setting modalInPopover to true, but it still doesn't work. I've searched the web but I only find unanswered questions. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible to show UIAlertController as popover on iPhone. That is not what's done in the Facebook app as I initially thought, on the grounds that you can't add icons to an UIAlertAction.

I managed to solve it by adding an UITableViewController to my storyboard and adding a popover segue. Following this tutorial helped me: http://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html